# Haskell - read list of persons

Tags: haskell, io

The problem sounds like this: write a program that reads a number n and then n persons, for each persons, read their name and age and then return the oldest persons/persons.

Example input:

```
3
Ion Ionel Ionescu
70
Gica Petrescu
99
Mustafa ben Muhamad
7
```

Example output

```
Oldest is Gica Petrescu (99 years).
```

My code so far:

```
readPers :: IO(String, Int)
readPers = do
    name <- getLine
    age <- readLn :: IO Int
    return (name, age)

readPerss :: (Ord t, Num t) => t -> [IO (String, Int)]
readPerss n
    | n > 0 = readPers : readPerss(n-1)
    | otherwise = []

pFunc = do
    print "Numer of persons:"
    n <- readLn :: IO Int
    let persons = readPerss n
    return persons
```

I first read n, then I try to make a list of persons using readPers and readPerss, but I am stuck, I don't know how to tackle it from that point forward and I guess that my implementation thus far is not quite right.

How should I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close! What you are doing in `readPerss :: (Ord t, Num t) => t -> [IO (String, Int)]` is returning a list of `IO` actions; each action returns a pair of `String` and `Int` when it is executed. Currently in `pFunc` you are only *building* this list of actions, storing it in a variable with `let`, and returning it from `pFunc`; you are never *executing* them with a `<-` “bind” statement.

There are a few simple ways to do what you want. The smallest change to your code that does what you want is to add `sequence`, which takes a *container of actions* and produces an *action that returns a container*:

```
sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)
```

Here `t` is `[]`, `m` is `IO`, and `a` is `(String, Int)`:

```
sequence :: [IO (String, Int)] -> IO [(String, Int)]
```

Another way is to rewrite `readPerss` so that it executes the actions directly, accumulating the `(String, Int)` *results* in a list instead of accumulating the `IO` *actions*:

```
readPerss :: (Ord t, Num t) => t -> IO [(String, Int)]
-- Change [IO …] to IO […]:         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

readPerss n
  | n > 0 = do
    pers <- readPers
    perss <- readPerss (n - 1)
    return (pers : perss)
  | otherwise = return []
```

I know you may not be supposed to use library functions if this is a homework assignment or exercise, but in typical code “repeat `x` action `n` times and accumulate the results” is often represented with `replicateM n x`:

```
replicateM :: Applicative m => Int -> m a -> m [a]
```

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. If I wanted to add the "sequence" to my code, where would that be? Also, there's no issue in using library functions

Comment: Also, how would it look using "replicateM"?

Comment: @GeorgeCernat: `sequence (readPerss n)` instead of `let persons = readPerss n; return persons`; alternatively, `replicateM n readPers` (and remove `readPerss` entirely)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I always do this (it is from a code challenge isn’t it). I always seperate IO and logic as soon as possible. Works perfect (unless N is very big).

```
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)

type Person = (String, Int)

main = do
    x <- getContents
    putStrLn $ program x

program :: String -> String
program s = “Oldest is “ ++ x ++ “ (“ ++ (show y) ++ “ years old).”
    where
    (x, y)  = solve persons
    persons = [(name, read age :: Int) | [name, age] <- chunksOf 2 . tail . lines $ s]

solve :: [Person] -> Person
solve ls = undefined
```

I leave the `undefined` to you.